# cy.visit() generates GET request to different page than requested in run mode

Tags: cypress

I have a very basic Cypress test, per below

```
describe("Tests for Site users Page", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login();
  });

  it("visits the manage users page", () => {
    cy.visit("/sites/2/users");
    cy.contains("Contact Name").should("exist");
});
```

For some reason, Cypress does not visit `/sites/2/users` and instead goes to `/sites/2/global` (even though I did not request that). Can someone please tell me what is going on and how this issue can be resolved? In my `cypress.json` i have the baseUrl set to `http://localhost:3002`. Note, in the screenshot I have seen it says `(new url) http://localhost:3002/sites/2/global` directly after attempting to visit `/sites/2/users`

Comment: I guess the login in `beforeEach()` hook is not successful, so the app (not Cypress) redirects you to `/sites/2/global`.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to apply what the answers are suggesting since it invalidates existing answers. If the answers have fixed part of the issue, but you're getting a new issue, please consider accepting the answer and asking a new question regarding the new issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of wild-guess territory, but maybe the login is not successful, and `/sites/2/global` is the default page for not-logged-in.

To test it, check where do you go with `cy.visit('/')` and with `cy.login()` commented out for the moment.

If it's `/sites/2/global`, then `cy.login()` is the problem.